# Bash script to monitor linux arp table and if any interface mac address changes, output to file

Tags: linux, bash

I want to write a Bash script that checks a Linux server's ARP table and if an interface MAC address changes, then it records it to a file with date/time that the change occurred.

I wrote the below script and tested it by changing the MAC address of an interface using `macchanger -m`, but it doesn't seem to work properly:

```
while true 10; do
   touch tempfile
   arp -e -v | awk '{print $1,$3,$5}' | column -t | sed "/Entries/d" >tempfile2
   if ! diff tempfile tempfile2 |grep ">"|cut -c 3-; then
        mv tempfile2 tempfile
        ts '[%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S]' <tempfile |
        tee -a /home/user/arp_script/arp_changes.txt
    fi
    sleep 10
done
```

Sample output from arp -e -v command:

```
Address                  HWtype  HWaddress           Flags Mask            Iface
192.168.21.1             ether   00:50:56:c0:00:08   C                     ens33
_gateway                 ether   00:50:56:e9:05:e3   C                     ens33
192.168.21.254           ether   00:50:56:e3:ec:7a   C                     ens33
192.168.48.1             ether   00:50:56:c0:00:01   C                     ens37
192.168.21.130           ether   00:0c:29:44:6e:f4   C                     ens33
Entries: 5  Skipped: 0  Found: 5
```

For example if the mac address of interface ens37 changes to b2:ee:83:a7:c7:c7, then I want the script to output to the file arp_changes.txt the following lines:

```
[2023-05-09 03:56:23] 192.168.48.1      00:50:56:c0:00:01       ens37
[2023-05-09 03:59:23] 192.168.48.1      b2:ee:83:a7:c7:c7       ens37
```

Comment: You haven't shared what "doesn't seem to work properly" means

Comment: I don't know how to make it to only output to that file the arp table line that changed only.

Comment: What does the output from `arp -e -v` look like?

Comment: (Like you discovered, pasting that information as a comment does not work very well. You'll want to [edit] your question and include the information there, where you can use proper code formatting etc.)

Comment: @tripleee I added a sample output of arp -e -v in my initial post

Answer (score 0):

`ts '[%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S]'tee` looks like it's missing a `|`: try `ts '[%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S]' | tee`

Also, I/O redirection using `>` means that the output file is overwritten each time. Are you sure you don't want to use `>>` to append to the file instead?

Comment: Thx. Edited with the above 2 corrections.  I don't know how to make it to only output to that file the arp table line that changed only.

Answer (score 0):

You can store the previous run in a temporary file, and only print if the results are different.

```
while true; do    
    touch tempfile
    if arp -e -v |   
        awk '!/^Address/ && !/^Entries/ {OFS="\t"; print $1,$3,$5}' |
        tee tempfile2 |
        diff -u tempfile - >tempfile3
    then
        sed -n '/^[-+] //p' tempfile3 |
        ts '[%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S]'
        mv tempfile2 tempfile
    fi
    sleep 10
done |
tee -a /home/user/arp_script/arp_changes.txt
```

A proper implementation would use `mktemp -d` to create a temporary directory for the temporary files, and use `trap` to remove it when the script is interrupted.

Perhaps a more elegant solution is to store the intermediate results in a variable.

```
previous=""
while true; do
    result=$(arp -e -v | awk '!/^Address/ && !/^Entries/{ OFS="\t"; print $1, $3, $5 }')
    if [[ "$result" != "$previous" ]]; then
        diff -u <(echo "$previous") <(echo "$result") |
        sed -n 's/^[-+] //p' |
        ts '[%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S]'
    fi
    previous=$result
    sleep 10
done |
tee -a /home/user/arp_script/arp_changes.txt
```

If you don't want to regard the first result as a change, it should not be hard to figure out how to extend the `if` condition to also not trigger if the previous result file or variable was empty.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work properly though: 
 cat arp_changes.txt 

    [2023-05-09 04:45:09] Address HWaddress Mask [2023-05-09 04:45:09] 192.168.21.1 
    00:50:56:c0:00:08 ens33 [2023-05-09 04:45:09] _gateway 00:50:56:e9:05:e3 ens33 [2023- 
    05-09 04:45:09] 192.168.21.254 00:50:56:e3:ec:7a ens33 [2023-05-09 04:45:09] 
    192.168.48.1 00:50:56:c0:00:01 ens37 [2023-05-09 04:45:09] 192.168.21.130 
    00:0c:29:44:6e:f4 ens33 [2023-05-09 06:51:52] Address HWaddress Mask [2023-05-09 
    06:51:52] 192.168.21.1 00:50:56:c0:00:08 ens33 ```

Comment: The output I am expecting is stated in my initial post, underneath:
"For example if the mac address of interface ens37 changes to b2:ee:83:a7:c7:c7, then I want the script to output to the file arp_changes.txt the following lines:"

Comment: Updated now with a version which extracts the old and the new value from `diff -u` output. It's still not clear if that's exactly what you want but thanks for updating your question; I hadn't noticed the latest addition.

Comment: Thnx for updating. What I need exactly is the script to log into the text file arp_changes.txt everytime the mac address of an interface changes, with timestamps included.

Comment: It does, but you have not revealed what exactly you want logged. I assumed from your example that you want the old and the new MAC for the changed interface.